# Scrapyd deployment can't find custom module？

Tags: python-3.x

My  scrapy crawl command works well
But when I wanted to deploy scrapyd, I met problems :

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
          File "c:\users\wzj-co~1\appdata\local\temp\articlespider-1556280457-dwm78ptr.egg\ArticleSpider\spiders\lagou.py", line 7, in <module>
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give more context for a question like this - at least the code snippet that is failing - but it looks like you're just missing dependencies in your deployment environment. Do you have some form of `import settings` line in your code? If yes, I suggest ensuring that the module is installed in your deployment environment and in a location where it can be found at runtime.